# regex continue only if positive lookahead has been matched at least once

Tags: python, regex

Using python: How do i get the regex to continue **only if** a positive lookahead has been matched at least once.

I'm trying to match:

```
Clinton-Orfalea-Brittingham Fellowship Program
```

Here's the code I'm using now:

```
dp2= r'[A-Z][a-z]+(?:-\w+|\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+'
print np.unique(re.findall(dp2, tt))
```

I'm matching the word, but it's also matching a bunch of other extraneous words. 
My thought was that I'd like the `\s[A-Z][a-z]` to kick in ONLY IF -\w+ has been hit at least once (or maybe twice). would appreciate any thoughts.

To clarify: I'm not aiming to match specifically this set of words, but to be able to generically match Proper noun- Proper noun- (indefinite number of times) and then a non-hyphenated Proper noun.

eg.
Noun-Noun-Noun Noun Noun

Noun-Noun Noun

Noun-Noun-Noun Noun

THE LATEST ITERATION:

dp5= r'(?:[A-Z][a-z]+-?){2,3}(?:\s\w+){2,4}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{m,n}` notation can be used to force the regex to ONLY MATCH if the previous expression exists between `m` and `n` times. Maybe something like

```
(?:[A-Z][a-z]+-?){2,3}\s\w+\s\w+ # matches 'Clinton-Orfalea-Brittingham Fellowship Program'
```

If you're SPECIFICALLY looking for `"Clinton-Orfalea-Brittingham Fellowship Program"`, why are you using Regex to find it? Just use `word in string`. If you're looking for things of the form: `Name-Name-Name Noun Noun`, this should work, but be aware that `Name-Name-Name-Name Noun Noun` won't, nor will `Name-Name-Name Noun Noun Noun` (In fact, something like `"Alice-Bob-Catherine Program"` will match not only that but whatever word comes after it!)

```
# Explanation

RE = r"""(?:        # Begins the group so we can repeat it
        [A-Z][a-z]+ # Matches one cap letter then any number of lowercase
        -?          # Allows a hyphen at the end of the word w/o requiring it
    ){2,3}          # Ends the group and requires the group match 2 or 3 times in a row
    \s\w+           # Matches a space and the next word
    \s\w+           # Does so again
    # those last two lines could just as easily be (?:\s\w+){2}
"""
RE = re.compile(RE,re.verbose) # will compile the expression as written
```

If you're looking specifically for hyphenated proper nouns followed by non-hyphenated proper nouns, I would do this:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+-(?:[A-Z][a-z]+(?:-|\s))+

# Explanation

RE = r"""[A-Z][a-z]+-   # Cap letter+small letters ending with a hyphen
         (?:            # start a non-cap group so we can repeat it
             [A-Z][a-z]+# As before, but doesn't require a hyphen
             (?:
                 -|\s   # but if it doesn't have a hyphen, it MUST have a space
             )          # (this group is just to give precedence to the |
         )+             # can match multiple of these.
    """
```

Comment: Thanks!  do you mind if you use the {m,n} on the code snippet to help me understand how to implement it under the conditions i want?

Comment: Thanks! how do i get it to also match Fellowship Program? so 'Clinton-Orfalea-Brittingham Fellowship Program'

Comment: @user3314418 it does that now -- I had to play with the regex tester for a bit :)

Comment: you are amazing, thanks!!! :) If you time for 1 more q: Could you break apart what you're doing? For instance, What happens when u put the noncapturing group (?:) in the front? I didnt think to do that.

Comment: sure I'll write out a `re.verbose`

Comment: Thanks so much adsmith. I also clarified my intentions above. I'm hoping to capture hyphenated propernouns followed by non-hyphenated proper nouns

Comment: Of any number of repetitions? That may be difficult, but I'll give it a shot! I updated with a `re.verbose`

Comment: Yup, the main condition is that the first letter is capitalized implying proper nouns

Comment: actually, i think it's solved by using dp5= r'(?:[A-Z][a-z]+-?){2,5}(?:\s\w+){2,5}'. What I still don't undersatnd is that I thought ?: meant NON-capturing group, so it wouldn't match anything- what am I missing?

Comment: @user3314418 `(?:)` gives a non-capturing group which means it won't be grabbed by `re.search.group(0)` and etc. I tend to default to them in case I do write a more complicated expression that requires them to be backreferenced. I updated my answer with a RE that should catch all references, just be careful of false positives.